# Inject dependencies into symfony messenger callable handler using Messenger as an independent component

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-messenger

Reading this manual https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/messenger.html#installation

I'm trying to integrate Messenger to Slim-based project

Manual handler registration is as simple as callable creation
The only thing I can't get is how to inject dependencies anyway
How should it be done properly via constructor in case like this

```php
namespace App\MessageHandler;

use App\Message\MyMessage;

class MyMessageHandler
{
    private $someRepo;

    public __constructor(SomeRepositoryInterface $someRepo)
    {
       $this->someRepo = $somRepo;
    }

    public function __invoke(MyMessage $message)
    {
        // Message processing...
    }
}
```

Comment: We need more information about version of Slim project, also the DI is different from Slim than Symfony, Symfony provides a Autowire tool to do that

Comment: it's slim4 + php-di

Comment: How is PHP-DI [configured](https://php-di.org/doc/definition.html)?

Comment: Autowiring and definition, no annotations

Answer (score 1):

Working example:

```
MessageBusInterface::class => static function (ContainerInterface $container) {
    $sendersMap = [
        EventInterface::class => ['sync://'],
        RedisEventInterface::class => ['message.sender.redis'],
    ];
    $middlewares = [
        $container->get(FailedExceptionMessageMiddleware::class),
        $container->get(MessageLoggerMiddleware::class),
        $container->get(DispatchAfterCurrentBusMiddleware::class),
        new SendMessageMiddleware(
            new SendersLocator(
                $sendersMap,
                $container
            ),
            $container->get(EventDispatcherInterface::class)
        ),
        new HandleMessageMiddleware(
            new EventHandlersLocator(
                $container
            ),
            true
        ),
        new HandleMessageMiddleware(
            new HandlersLocator(
                $container
            ),
            true
        ),
    ];
    return new MessageBus(new SymfonyMessageBus($middlewares));
},
'message.redis.connection' => static function (ContainerInterface $container) {
    /** @var Redis $redis */
    $redis = $container->get(Redis::class);
    return new Connection(
        [
            'stream' => $container->get('CACHE_NAMESPACE'),
            'group' => 'symfony',
            'consumer' => $_ENV['QUEUE_CONSUMER_NAME'] ?? 'consumer',
            'delete_after_ack' => true,
        ],
        ['host' => $container->get('REDIS_HOST'), 'port' => $container->get('REDIS_PORT'),],
        [],
        $redis
    );
},
'sync://' => static function (ContainerInterface $container) {
    return new SyncTransport($container->get(MessageBusInterface::class));
},
'message.sender.redis' => static function (ContainerInterface $container) {
    return new RedisSender(
        $container->get('message.redis.connection'),
        new PhpSerializer()
    );
},
'message.receiver.redis' => static function (ContainerInterface $container) {
    return new RedisReceiver(
        $container->get('message.redis.connection'),
        new PhpSerializer()
    );
},
'retry.strategy.locator' => static function () {
    $builder = new DI\ContainerBuilder();
    $builder->useAutowiring(false);
    $builder->useAnnotations(false);
    $container = $builder->build();
    $container->set(
        'message.receiver.redis',
        static function () {
            // +12sec(1), +1min(2), +5min(3), +25min(4), ...
            return new MultiplierRetryStrategy(1, 12000, 5);
        }
    );

    return $container;
},
'retry.senders.locator' => static function (ContainerInterface $c) {
    $builder = new DI\ContainerBuilder();
    $builder->useAutowiring(false);
    $builder->useAnnotations(false);
    $container = $builder->build();
    $container->set('message.receiver.redis', $c->get('message.sender.redis'));

    return $container;
},
'failure.senders.locator' => static function ($c) {
    $builder = new DI\ContainerBuilder();
    $builder->useAutowiring(false);
    $builder->useAnnotations(false);
    $container = $builder->build();
    $container->set('message.receiver.redis', $c->get(DatabaseSender::class));

    return $container;
},
DatabaseConnectionInterface::class => DI\autowire(DatabaseConnection::class),
RetryStrategyInterface::class => DI\autowire(MultiplierRetryStrategy::class),
EventDispatcherInterface::class => static function (ContainerInterface $container) {
    $dispatcher = new EventDispatcher();
    $dispatcher->addSubscriber(
        new SendFailedMessageForRetryListener(
            $container->get('retry.senders.locator'),
            $container->get('retry.strategy.locator'),
            null,
            $dispatcher
        )
    );
    $dispatcher->addSubscriber(
        new SendFailedMessageToFailureTransportListener(
            $container->get('failure.senders.locator')
        )
    );
    $dispatcher->addSubscriber(
        new AddErrorDetailsStampListener()
    );
    $dispatcher->addSubscriber(
        new StopWorkerOnMessageLimitListener(10)
    );
    $dispatcher->addSubscriber(
        new StopWorkerOnTimeLimitListener(300)
    );
    $dispatcher->addListener(
        WorkerMessageFailedEvent::class,
        function (WorkerMessageFailedEvent $e) use ($container) {
            $handler = $container->get(WorkerMessageFailed::class);
            $handler($e);
        }
    );
    $dispatcher->addListener(
        WorkerMessageHandledEvent::class,
        function (WorkerMessageHandledEvent $e) use ($container) {
            $handler = $container->get(WorkerMessageHandled::class);
            $handler($e);
        }
    );
    $dispatcher->addListener(
        SendMessageToTransportsEvent::class,
        function (SendMessageToTransportsEvent $e) use ($container) {
            $handler = $container->get(SendMessageToTransports::class);
            $handler($e);
        }
    );

    return $dispatcher;
},
```